# How to get Product url and show in detail page even it is non visibility mode?

Tags: magento-1.7, overrides, url-rewrite

By default Magento does not allow the product which has 'not visibility in frontend' mode to avoid showing the product in listing and detail page. When user hit the previously loaded url, it redirects to 404 since it is not visibility in front end mode. I am in situation to load this product in its detail page only.(catalog_product_view).

I am extending Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View to check. I am stuck now on how to get url and view page for non visibility product. kindly advice

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve. You have products that are "not visible" and still want to be able to see them?

Comment: @JulienLachal actually my need is , item should not be in listing page and only want to show item in detail page.

Comment: but how would people be able to find them?

Comment: @JulienLachal Doing jewellery site in which one item will have matched item called upsell collection. I extend upsell class and show the non visibility matched item.here i want to give url for non visibility item to know their details.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but what you need is to display upsell products on specific product. Then when a customer clicks on it, they should be redirected to the upsell product page, but this products shouldn't be listed in categories nor search? Am I right?

Comment: @JulienLachal yes exactly :)

Comment: Then what is the problem with that? Can't you put your invisble products on the "upsell" section of the specific product that will hold the upsell collection?

Comment: @JulienLachal i get non visibility item from upsel collection by extending its block class. but i need url and its respective page from catalog-product-view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't make it too complicated, you should not need to rewrite any core files. If I understand your issue correct, you need to make the products "Visible in Catalog" but do not assign them to any category.

Comment: fentabulous ! yes this will work. My solution is complicated but will work for sure now. But this is the best solution ever for this issue. I AM A FOOL !

Comment: but if he needs to keep visibility in "not visible individually", then this will not work. Only my solution will do the trick. :) don't you have any other suggestion on that point ?

Comment: @fab thanks now items is not shown in detail page and coming in detail page. only thing is how to restrict that item in search page ?

Comment: change visibility to "search"

Comment: I don't undersand "Visible in Catalog" does not make them visible in search, only "Visible in Catalog AND Search" does.

Comment: @Dinesh : play with visibility. Understand its power

Comment: fab and programmer_rkt  thanks it is working as expected :)

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer :** I don't understand why do you need this ? But I will give you some hint to sort out the issue.

For catalog product view page, product visibility checking is actually takes place in a helper class. Most specifically it happens in `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product`. Take look on the `initProduct` method there. You can see that it checks for product's visibility as like this.

```
if (!$this->canShow($product)) {
    return false;
}
```

If you further investigate, we can conclude that we will get a no found page for two conditions.

1. If the `status` of your product is `disable`.
2. Product is not assign with current website/store that is viewing.

In order to change this default behaviour, my recommendation is to create a new attribute with name `visibility_in_product_view` for every product and then make it a select option with value `1` for `yes` and `2` for `no`. Now set this value to yes, for every product that you need this exception.

Now rewrite the helper class method `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product::canShow()` as like this.

```
<?php
class Namespace_Modulename_Helper_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product
{
    //use to check product view visibility status
    const VISIBILITY_IN_PRODUCT_VIEW_PAGE = 1;

    public function canShow($product, $where = 'catalog')
    {
        if (is_int($product)) {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product);
        }

        /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */

        if (!$product->getId()) {
            return false;
        }
        if ($product->isVisibleInCatalog()) {
            if ($product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                 $frontname = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getModuleName();
                 $controller = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
                 $action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getActionName();
                if ($frontname.$controller.$action == 'catalogproductview' && Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE == $product->getVisibility()) {
                    if ($product->getVisibilityInProductView() == self::VISIBILITY_IN_PRODUCT_VIEW_PAGE) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }  
}
```

This is the part that do the trick here

```
        if ($product->isVisibleInCatalog()) {
            if ($product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                $frontname = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getModuleName();
                 $controller = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
                 $action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getActionName();
                if ($frontname.$controller.$action == 'catalogproductview' && Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE == $product->getVisibility()) {
                    if ($product->getVisibilityInProductView() == self::VISIBILITY_IN_PRODUCT_VIEW_PAGE) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
```

Here first it check whether product is enabled or not. If enabled, it will check whether product is visible or not. If product is not visible, then it will check whether `not visible individually` is the real cause the previous condition. If that is yes, then we will check whether exception is provided for view page by inspecting the status of our custom attribute. If exception enabled, then it will show in product view page.

Hence problem solved

Comment: thanks.Doing jewellery site in which one item will have matched item called upsell collection. I extend upsell class and shown the non visibility matched item.here i want to give url for non visibility item to show their detail page

Comment: yes. Make a custom attribute to do this. Then set that custom attribute to yes for all those matched products.  It will be the most elegant way. Then rewrite the above helper class. Go through the answer. You will get much more idea. Ask me if you have any doubts

Comment: $product->getVisibilityInProductView() is custom function ?

Comment: its a magic method. It is equivalent to `$product->getData('visibility_in_product_view')`. In order to work it properly you need to create a custom attribute with attribute code `visibility_in_product_view`.

Comment: but items comes in listing page catalog-category-view.It should not come in listing page ,this logic works in detail page.

Comment: I done an edit. Can you check now ?

Comment: @programmer-rkt seems not working in any case.using custom attribute check, item should not coming in listing page as well as search page and should come in detail page

Comment: now it is not coming in any page ?

Comment: @programmer-rkt yes not working.when i set to yes for custom attr and set visibility to catalog search. Items is coming in both detail page and listing page, search page. My need it should come only in detail page and not in listing,search page

Comment: I have edited my answer again. It will now check whether page viewing is product view page. I think you have misunderstand me. custom attribute validation only takes place when product visibility is set to "not visible individually". For all other cases, it will work as in default case

Comment: so set product `visibilility` to `not visible individually` and then set custom attribute to `yes`. check whether product is visible only in product view page

Comment: @programmer-rkt thanks a lot. I will check and let you know

Comment: check @fab answer. It will work. use my answer only if you need to set `visibility` to "not visible individually" and yet you need to do some exception for some product.

Comment: Very helpful.... :)