# Custom visibility on products

Tags: magento-1.9

I'd like to be able to set some custom type of visibility to some products. I'd like these products to be just like 'Not visible individually' but to be able to add their url, in other product's descriptions.
In default magento settings, '**Not visible individually**' products return **404 error**, when I try to access their details page directly using url.

Is it possible to create a new type of visibility or just remove the 404 error from these kind of products?

Comment: The second answer for http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37666/how-to-get-product-url-and-show-in-detail-page-even-it-is-non-visibility-mode might be what you are after.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of a new type just set them to `Visible in catalog` and don't add them to a category. This way they can be reached via direct URL but not navigated to via catalog or search

Comment: that could be a good solution, but I need to keep categories active